# How can I read in excel files by looking for a string pattern?

Tags: r

I need to read in a bunch of files that are scattered across different directories.

The problem is, these files all have slightly different naming variations such as:

7-2018 RECON.xlsx
RECON 06-2019.xlsx
5-31-2017 RECON LINKED.xlsx

I want to read in excel files to look for the keyword "RECON" in the file name.

I tried using the contains function in the read_excel function - didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want list.files https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list.files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could identify the list of relevant files and get their paths with something like:

```
> normalizePath(list.files(pattern="Rmd", ignore.case=TRUE, recursive=TRUE))
[1] "/Users/david/Dropbox (DaveArmstrong)/9590/Lecture1/Lecture1.Rmd"    
[2] "/Users/david/Dropbox (DaveArmstrong)/9590/Lecture2/lec2_inclass.Rmd"
[3] "/Users/david/Dropbox (DaveArmstrong)/9590/Lecture2/lecture2.rmd"    
[4] "/Users/david/Dropbox (DaveArmstrong)/9590/Lecture3/lecture3.rmd"
```

You would probably want a pattern like "`.*RECON.*\\.xlsx$`" which would find `<anything>RECON<anything>.xlsx<end of string>`.  You could save the result as a vector of file names and then loop over them to read them in.

Comment: you regex isn't quite correct. I think you are looking for ".*RECON.*\.xlsx$". But even then the first .* isn't needed, "RECON.*\.xlsx$" should suffice. Alternatively if all files are xlsx in the dir your pattern can just be "RECON".

Comment: @noah Thanks, I needed to add the backticks around the expression.  And you're right about the rest.